# Make a ajax post request to a vert.x server

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, http, vert.x

i want to make a small code that just send a POST request to a server and print "hi" if the server answer.
I have this ajax function that realize a post request to vert.x server:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:9999',
        data: {message:tmpMessage},
        async:false
    }).done(function() {alert("succes");})
    .fail(function() { alert("fail");})
    .always(function() { alert("complete");});
```

And this java code which is a vert.x server that just gives a response back when he recieve POST request.

```
httpServer.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("incoming request!");

        if(request.method() == HttpMethod.POST){
             HttpServerResponse response = request.response();
                response
                .end();
        }
    }
});
```

But it never goes in the callBack function .done(function() {aler("success");} and i don't understand why. I think that it's not the way to use the HttpServerResponse but i can't find a proper answer anywhere. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the type for your `POST`, but even in that way you are comparing it looks *a little bit suspicious*.

Anyway, assuming you are using Vert.x 2.x, change your code section for this:

```
if ("POST".equals(request.method())) {
  request.response().end();
}
```

...and you are good to go.

**NOTE:** You can find a type to compare `POST` in any other library/framework, like those constants or enums.